# Remove Duplicate In Array Using Pure Javascript Or Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, duplicates

I seem to only find ways to remove duplicates from an array using other JS libraries but I'm looking to do it in pure JS or typescript since I'm working on an Angular project.

My problem is that I may get an array that has duplicate entries, such as this one:

```
data [0: {Id: 1, Definition: "House"},
      1: {Id: 1, Definition: "House"}]
```

And I want to filter it out so that I only get

```
data [0: {Id: 1, Definition: "House"}]
```

I've tried it using this method but I still get duplicate entries

```
let uniqueArray = data.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return data.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

Comment: This `data.indexOf(item) == pos` will always be true in your case, since find will test Object identity. You need something like: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/hnLowjy2/

Comment: how do you want to filter out the duplicate entries? Is it only based on the id key?

Comment: @Ashish either compare the ID or the String in "Definition"... both will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve what you want in this way:

You can check if the value is already there in your final array using ['some'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
data = [{Id: 1, Definition: "House"}, {Id: 1, Definition: "House"}]

const finalOut = []
data.forEach((value) => {
    if (!finalOut.some(x=> (x.Id === value.Id || x.Definition === value.Definition))) 
   {
        finalOut.push(value)
    }
})
```

You can also achieve this by ['reduce'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in clean and elegant way:

```
const finalOut2 = data.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.some(x=> (x.Id === cur.Id || x.Definition === cur.Definition)) ? acc : acc.concat(cur), [])
```

As suggested by @Ezequiel using `some` inside `forEach` or `reduce` making the time complexity of *order of n square*. For smaller sets of data using `reduce` and `some` is an elegant approach. But if you are dealing with arrays of very large length, you must avoid *order of n square time complexity* Here is one such approach with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
//Here storing every value of data is inside lookupObj after filtering it. 
//And checking if value is filtered based on if key of the value inside lookupObj

const lookupObj = {} 
const finalOut3 = data.filter(
    x => {
        const is_unique = !(lookupObj[`Id_${x.Id}`] || lookupObj[`Id_${x.Definition}`])
        lookupObj[`Id_${x.Id}`] = true
        lookupObj[`Id_${x.Definition}`] = true
        return is_unique
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this finally worked!

Comment: Do be aware that this method runs in O(n²) or quadratic time, because hidden in here is a nested loop. This isn't a problem with small arrays, but gets slow if data.length becomes large. The other methods outlined in this answer run in O(n) or linear time and don't suffer the same fate.

Comment: I have updated the answer with new function to reduce O(n²) complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Id` key of the object to get the unique object using `array#reduce` in an object accumulator and get all the object of this object using `Object.values()`.

```js
let data = [{Id: 1, Definition: "House"},{Id: 1, Definition: "House"}, {Id: 2, Definition: "House2"}, {Id: 2, Definition: "House2"}],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) =>  {
      r[o.Id] = r[o.Id] || {...o};
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: sadly I get a syntax error
[ts] Property "values" is not available for type "ObjectConstructor"

Comment: You can use `Object.prototype.values = function(obj) {
                                var res = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            res.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
};`

Answer (score 0):

If the ID is what determines identity, then you could use a Map or a plain Object to dedupe. Same IDs will take the same spot on the map, so you end up with unique objects (if the above assumptions about IDs hold).

```
let data = [{Id: 1, Definition: "House"}, {Id: 1, Definition: "House"}];
let idToObj = {};
data.forEach((o) => idToObj[o.Id] = o);
let uniqueArray = Object.values(idToObj);
```

EDIT: In case that you want the same but you may have objects with the same ID but differing in other fields, a Map comes in handy because it can take whole objects as keys:

```
let data = [{Id: 1, Definition: "House1"}, {Id: 1, Definition: "House2"}];
let map = new Map();
data.forEach((o) => map.set(o, true));
let uniqueArray = [...map.keys()];
```

Comment: Ohh yes, fixed now :)