# return array from comparing to arrays _ lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

```
let a =  [{
    a:1,
    b:3,
    c:[1, 2, 6]
    },
 {
    a:3,
    b:10,
    c:[2, 5, 4]
    },
 {
    a:4,
    b:3,
    c:[7, 12, 6]
    },
 {
    a:4,
    b:12,
    }]

let b = [2, 6]
```

I want to return an array from **a** object that matches from b arrays.

I used :

```
lodash.forEach(b , (value)=>{
   lodash.filter(a, {c: value})
}
```

but this doesnt work . I tried to simple my code for better underestanding.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: expect the objects that c.values are common with second array

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @babakabadkheir - Still not clear, can you please share the response?

Comment: Possible Duplicate Of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52514026/remove-duplicate-in-array-using-pure-javascript-or-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the array by looking if the values of `b` are included in `c`.

```js
var a = [{ a: 1, b: 3, c: [1, 2, 6] }, { a: 3, b: 10, c: [2, 5, 4] }, { a: 4, b: 3, c: [7, 12, 6] }, { a: 4, b: 12 }],
    b = [2, 6],
    result = a.filter(({ c = [] }) => b.some(v => c.includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For getting only items who match completely, you could use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
var a = [{ a: 1, b: 3, c: [1, 2, 6] }, { a: 3, b: 10, c: [2, 5, 4] }, { a: 4, b: 3, c: [7, 12, 6] }, { a: 4, b: 12 }],
    b = [2, 6],
    result = a.filter(({ c = [] }) => b.every(v => c.includes(v)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To find objects with `c` contain all `b` values you can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
let a =  [{ a: 1, b: 3, c: [1, 2, 6] }, { a: 3, b: 10, c: [2, 5, 4] }, { a: 4, b: 3, c: [7, 12, 6] }, { a: 4, b: 12 }];

    let b = [2, 6]

    console.log(a.filter(({c = []}) => b.every(v => c.includes(v))));
```

if you want common values use [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `Array.every()`:

```js
let a =  [{ a: 1, b: 3, c: [1, 2, 6] }, { a: 3, b: 10, c: [2, 5, 4] }, { a: 4, b: 3, c: [7, 12, 6] }, { a: 4, b: 12 }];

        let b = [2, 6]

        console.log(a.filter(({c = []}) => b.some(v => c.includes(v))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to filter objects in array `a` that have atleast one value in `c` which exists in `b` array.

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) & [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let a=[{a:1,b:3,c:[1,2,6]},{a:3,b:10,c:[2,5,4]},{a:4,b:3,c:[7,12,6]},{a:4,b:12,}];
let b=[2,6];

let result = a.filter(v => v.c && v.c.some(v1 => b.includes(v1)));
console.log(result);
```

You can use **lodash** as follows

```js
let a=[{a:1,b:3,c:[1,2,6]},{a:3,b:10,c:[2,5,4]},{a:4,b:3,c:[7,12,6]},{a:4,b:12,}];
let b=[2,6];

let result = _.filter(a, v => v.c && _.some(v.c, c => _.includes(b,c)));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want - you can do it in pure JS:

```js
 

let a =  [{
a:1,
b:3,
c:[1, 2, 6]
},
 {
a:3,
b:10,
c:[2, 5, 4]
},
 {
a:4,
b:3,
c:[7, 12, 6]
},
 {
a:4,
b:12,
}]

let b = [2, 6]

let c = a.filter(({ c = [] }) => c ? b.some(n => c.includes(n))) : false;

console.log(c);
```